# Writing logs to file

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have some troubles while writing logs from log4net to the file. I seem to do all as described in manual, but that does not work. Here is my logging.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Please help with an example of configuration file which actually works.

Comment: Are you Configuring the Xml setting... http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overload_5.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You don't seem to have a `<root>` element that references your appender:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

    <log4net>
      <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="250KB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
      </appender>
      <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a point. Also I've found out that you can put <level value = "ALL" /> to redirect all logs to the file.

Answer (score 86):

Here is a complete step-by-step guide to adding Log4Net to your project, under Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5.

1. Add a new C# console app to your solution.
2. Select `Tools >> Library Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages For Solution` and search for `log4net`. Install it, and select which project(s) you want to add the log4net references.
   [image]
3. Edit `Program.cs`:

```cs
using System;
namespace Log4Net
{    
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
                (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Writing to \"log.txt\" in the same directory as the .exe file.\n");
            log.Info("Info logging");
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error("This is my error", e);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("[any key to exit]");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Add `log4.config`, right click and select `Properties` then select `Copy to Output Directory - Copy If Newer`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="250KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

5. Edit `App.Config` so it matches the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Config" value="log4.config"/>
        <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="False"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

6. Run the program and observe the file `log.txt` that is created in the output `\bin\Debug\` directory:

   ```
   2013-08-10 11:54:26,798 [10] INFO  Log4Net.Program [(null)] - Info logging
   2013-08-10 11:54:26,824 [10] ERROR Log4Net.Program [(null)] - This is my error
   System.Exception: Exception!
      at Log4Net.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Test\Log4Net\Program.cs:line 14
   ```
7. In the future, if you want to add `log4net` to another Project, select `Tools >> Library Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages For Solution` select `log4net` and click `Manage` then tick the Projects you want to add `log4net` to.
   [image]

Comment: Just a note on the configSections: "If this element is in a configuration file, it must be the first child element of the <configuration> element." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903350(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: could you elaborate on the roll the App.config settings play?

Comment: @jxramos Settings in app.config control everything to do with logging, including whether it writes to a file, what format each line is, if it writes to the console, etc. It's probably easier to look at the log4net docs for all of the options.

Answer (score 21):

Did you call the configure method when the application starts for the first time ?

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

If yes. You should be good. Check the file permissions on the disk you are writing.

If you want you can enable log4net internal debugging also to figure out what is wrong.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#troubleshooting

Comment: you could also enable log4net internal debugging, as detailed here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#troubleshooting

Comment: For an .NET web app, does this line only need to be called once? i.e. in the Application_Start() of the Global.asax file? Or on each users session start i.e. Session_Start() ?

Comment: @paul : Added that to my answer. Thanks Paul

Comment: @Seany84 : Not for each session. Only once when the application starts. thats y we put this in the Application_start event in global.asax which will fire only once in the application life time.

Comment: @Shyju Thanks for clearing that up for me. I recently introduced log4net into a commercial application and I am going to have to move this Configure() to the Application_Start(). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things that you can do:

One, if you want to use a seperate config file, by adding the following to you app.config file it will configure logging automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Config" value="log4.config"/>
        <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="False"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Otherwise, you need to initiate logging in the start of your application.

```
//Initiate logging based on web.config file
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

// Create a logger for use in this class
log4net.ILog log4 = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Answer (score 3):

Fantastic. The answers are correct... except that they weren't working for me

Searched the net and finally discovered I was missing the following line in Assembly.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]
```